# Sizing an image from external source

Tags: html, image, sizing

I've an image, actual its an image from a youtube video which is offered by youtube.
If I put it into my DOM and add some sizing attributes to it, they are ignored. Why?

F.e.:

```
<div id="item-strip" style="width: 100%; left: 0px; bottom: 20px; height: 5.67010309278351%;">
<a href="#" id="strip-item_1" class="strip-item" data-width="50" data-height="50" style="left: 855px; opacity: 0.3;">
    <img src="fileadmin/_processed_/csm_Breakbot_45131e3f4b.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="">
</a>
<a href="#" id="strip-item_2" class="strip-item" data-width="50" data-height="50" style="left: 915px; opacity: 0.3;">
    <img src="fileadmin/_processed_/csm_BusyP_132ca062c9.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="">
</a>
<a href="#" id="strip-item_3" class="strip-item" data-width="50" data-height="50" style="left: 975px; opacity: 0.3;">
    <img src="fileadmin/_processed_/csm_Justice_Gaspard_320_1_096a62ce10.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="">
</a>
<a href="#" id="strip-item_7" class="strip-item" data-width="50" data-height="50" style="left: 1035px; opacity: 0.3;">
    <img src="fileadmin/_processed_/csm_mindwarping2_bbf5c05a70.gif" width="50" height="50" alt="">
</a>
<a href="#" id="strip-item_6" class="strip-item" data-width="50" data-height="50" style="left: 1095px; opacity: 0.3;">
    <img src="fileadmin/_processed_/csm_mindwarping_38c238a504.gif" width="50" height="50" alt="">
</a>
<a href="#" id="strip-item_4" class="strip-item" data-width="50" data-height="50" style="left: 1155px; opacity: 1;">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/7buLSy3BXG0/0.jpg" height="50" width="50">
</a><span class="strip-item-frame" style="border-color: green; left: 1155px; width: 63px; height: 47px;"></span>
```

I'm adding these images via a php viewhelper for fluid in TYPO3. All processed local pictures are shown with the correct size.

There are no additional styleattributes for the images. the anchor-tag has the position.

My solution now is instead giving the height and width attribute, I am adding the css inline-style via my viewhelper. this works.

Comment: It works fine for me on Chrome; it's scaled down to 67x50px. Perhaps your browser also needs a `width`?

Comment: are you sure there is no css that is automatically applied to omg tags?

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: Works just fine for me... http://jsfiddle.net/w341utxq/

Comment: the problem was my CMS (TYPO3). I wrote my own viewhelper in fluid and now it works. Thanks.